# my website sitemap on google webmasters indexing is too slow

Tags: seo, google-search-console, sitemap

website content is very heavy and indexed are only 1500 from 1000000.
can you tell me what is problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I originally read you question as the number of indexed pages from your sitemap is 1500 and that you are worried. Then I thought about it. Perhaps there are things you need to know.

If your site is new, then it will take quite a while for a new site to be indexed. I am not sure how old your site is, but it can take as much as a year for some sites to sink into any search engine. You can use a `site:example.com` search to see how many pages are indexed. Please know that the index refreshes periodically each day and that this number can fluctuate. You will also want to pay attention to the number in the Google Search Console (formerly Webmaster Tools) on the index status page. It is possible that both numbers will not agree. That is okay.

Search engines like original content. Search engines do not like thin content. Search engines prefer faster sites. Search engines do not like errors or broken links to resources. You appear to have all of these issues. For example, your home page took 25 seconds to download and is in the bottom 5% of all sites tested. All of your images on fastpic.ru are failing to download. Using a Russian site to host your images may be putting you into the bad neighborhood category where search engines cannot trust your site.

*I will not analyze all of the issues you have. Just know, you have some work to do before your site can perform at all well.*

[Original Answer]

Pages indexed and pages indexed from sitemap when looking at the Google Search Console (formerly Webmaster Tools) are two different things and should not be confused. It is possible that for any sitemap, the pages indexed when looking at the sitemaps page may not be accurate or even close to accurate. The number returned is based upon a recent audit.

For example, my sitemap has well over 700,000 pages listed and the reported number of indexed pages according to the sitemap page GSC is around 655,000 while the index status page indicates a number nearly matching the number of pages listed in the sitemap. There is over a 50,000 page difference all the time.

*Why is this the case?*

For the most part, any sitemap is largely ignored and only used to compare pages you report with pages found using a traditional crawl. If Google can crawl your site, it will only use the sitemap to compare to the results they see when crawling. The number you are seeing, 1500, is the number of pages that Google has successfully compared to your sitemap and is **NOT** an indication that **only** 1500 pages from your sitemap exists within the index.

It is a confusing and unclear page, granted, and Google could do a much better job of explaining this. We get this question here a lot. My advice is to fully ignore this page. It is generally useless. The only time it gets interesting is when the numbers shift while doing a new audit. Otherwise, I have found the metric to be a misnomer and annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make text more english, especially the text in the title tag, and in Webmaster tools, select the website domain, then the gear icon, then "site settings" then for crawl rate select "Limit Google's maximum crawl rate" and select the right-most point on the slider that appears so that Google can scan your site faster. Just make sure you don't have anything installed on your server that limits the connection speed for Google.